# Android : How to reuse Jars already included in an application

Tags: android, jar

I have an application **(Say A)** which included some external jars.

I want to create a new application **(Say B)**, In which I want to use same external jars(Included in A) without adding same again in project B.

Both Applications will always present in device 
I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead create a **Library Module** that will contain the common external jars to be used by different apps.
Check out this [Library Module link](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules) to the Android developer docs.

It states there that:

> If you have source code and resources that are common to multiple Android projects, you can move them to a library module so that it is easier to maintain across applications and versions.

and:

> A library module can include a JAR library

and:

> A library module can depend on an external JAR library

So you can have a library module (say **C**) with the jar files, then add the library module as a dependency to both **A** and **B**.

Comment: Thanks ginomempin..!!
But the problem is that I can't make Application 'A' as Library. I need to maintain it as normal application

Comment: @GauravTiwari There's no need to make your `A` as a library, you should create a _separate_ library module (say `C`) containing only _common JAR files_ and then configure your `A` and `B` to use `C` as their dependencies. Clear?

Comment: I mean you have to move the jar files from 'A' to a Library Module. Then rebuild 'A' and 'B' using the lib module. In order to share the JARs, it has to be done during build time. There is no way to share jar files when the applications are running on the device.